# How to allow specific comments (parsing hints) with tsconfig?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tsconfig, istanbul

Is there a way to allow specific comments in the compiled js files with tsconfig while using the `--removeComments: true` flag in `compilerOptions`?

I use istanbul for unit test coverage and it allows skipping coverage tracking for specific lines/method by using the `/* istanbul ignore next */` parsing hint.  Now when I am using this in my current setup, this comment gets removed during compile time and the method isnt skipped in coverage.

Is this possible to achieve?

I have tried setting `removeComments` to false and verified that my coverage does increase after this. This verifies that the `/* istanbul ignore next */` parsing hint is indeed being removed because of the above flag.

I have tried using `// @ts-ignore` before the parsing hint but that also didn't help.